# Is using if(!dead) similar to if(dead ==false)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my C# code. Can I write it as down below? isDead is a bool.

```
if (isDead == false){
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}
```

```
if (!isDead){
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can and should use the second way

Comment: It does exactly the same thing ... However usually you would rather go for the logical operator `!` instead of a `==`

Comment: nothing to do with all that directly - but i would use `isAlive` instead. i mean i guess its what the character is supposed to be most of the time, isnt it? :)

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it should work. ! switches the bool, so if its true it becomes false, and if its false it becomes true. So if dead is false, then that will return true and the if statement will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and another thing you can do is to convert the second if condition to be validated in the first if condition to make the code cleaner.

An if statement identifies which statement to run based on the value of a Boolean expression. so, since dead is a bool type argument, it is enough to for the condition to validate and there is no need for explicit comparision.

```
if (!isDead && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
      rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes! It's similar. I prefer, the second one.

Comment: Why? And when one might prefer one syntax over the other?

Comment: I prefer the first variant, because it is the standard variant. It is good to write code with common conventions because then the code is easier to read. Also, it is better if they work in a team to use the same convention.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, anything that resolves to a Boolean can be used without comparing to another Boolean and `!` can be used to flip the Bool if you need. There are situations where `== false` can be more readable than `!` negating so I personally wouldn't say "you must always.."

You might find it more useful, as a general programming concept, to make your booleans have a positive rather than negative intent.

By this in this particular context I'm not so much talking about "dead" as negative in comparison to "alive" being positive(as general concepts), but more that if you're finding that most of your checking is asking if something is alive, by calling for `!isDead` then it's probably going to make the code more readable to flip your Boolean to tracking `isAlive`

In other contexts it's generally better to use a positive slant on variable names so you don't end up with code that is full of double negations .. Perhaps like using `Enabled` or `Readable` instead of `!Disabled` or `!Unreadable`